# How to display Emoji v5.0 character in HTML only for clients that support it?

Tags: html, unicode, emoji

There's some great icons in the [Full Emoji List v5.0](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) including variations on skin tone for the human ones. In particular, I want to display the "woman detective: medium-dark skin tone" which has a code of U+1F575 U+1F3FE U+200D U+2640 U+FE0F ... new OS/browsers display this correctly but older ones show the generic detective (U+1F575) followed by a string of question-box glyphs.

How does one go about having the display use the Emoji v5.0 character only for browsers that support it and have a fallback character for browsers that don't?